# How to have different paths for different repositories in SVN Server?

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I'm new to Visual SVN Server (`Version 3.2.2`) and I'm using it to create repositories.

When I create a repository in the server, it takes the configured **default** path which is **"C/Repositories"**.

I know that the path can be changed by righ-clicking on root node and changing the storage properties but is there any way to have ***different paths for different repositories***?

```
For e.g. 
<br/>Repository_1 in "C/Repositories" 
<br/>and 
<br/>Repository_2 in "D\Repositories",
```

considering that `Repository_1` and `Repository_2` are under **same root node**.

Answer (score 0):

> is there any way to have different paths for different repositories?

"No" in common